# How to set cascade select2 value onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have three select2 lists next to each other, first independent, second dependent on first, third dependent on second (cascading lists), that works as expected when I normally populate them by selecting some options. I have created a dynamic action that fills these items with values that I calculate when I click a button, but after the click, only the first select2 have selected value. The second and third value remains empty. When I check the session, all items have value in them. It appears that when I click the button that for a millisecond list are filled but after that values disappear. So my question is, how do I transfer values from server-side to client-side. I tried to refresh items, I have played with jQuery without success, also I have tried to separate dynamic action to set values separately but nothing worked. Values populate correctly so that is not the problem. Please help

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is lazy loading checked for the select2 that are subject to this behaviour (Item -> Setting -> Lazy loading)? If so try unchecking it